# How to avoid Linq exception using aggregate operators on empty collection?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I like to write synthetic query on db tables like the following:

```
Decimal sum = MyDataContext.MyTable.Where(el => el.Client == selectedClien).Sum(el => el.Value.GetValueOrDefault(0));
```

Unfortunately it throws an error if the where clause return no elements at all.
Before using .Sum I should check with .Any if I have some elements but the resulting code is ugly compared with the initial one. Don't think putting a try/catch block is a good solution.

Do you have something better that the following code to suggest ?

```
if (MyDataContext.MyTable.Where(el => el.Client == selectedClien).Any())
  sum =  MyDataContext.MyTable.Where(el => el.Client == selectedClien).Sum(el => el.Value.GetValueOrDefault(0));
else sum = 0;
```

Thanks
Filippo

Added after some more investigation:

```
MyDataContext.MyTable.Where(el => el.Client == selectedClien).Sum(el => el.Value).GetValueOrDefault(0)
```

The code above works well when the collection is empty. The reason I put 'GetValueOrDefault(0)' in the lambda inside .Sum() is the field 'Value' is Decimal?, so it could be null. I have not yet tested the case where some elements have null values.

Comment: Sum will return 0 if there are no elements. Other operators such as Average can have a problem, but Sum should be fine...

Comment: You could append a dummy element with `Value = 0` after the `Where`. That won't change the sum, but return `0` if there are no other elements.

Comment: "Unfortunately it throws an error if the where clause return no elements at al" - Tell us more about this error.

Comment: it is a System.InvalidOperationException. Translating from my language it says: it is not possible to assign a null value to a System.Decimal. The exception seems to be generated by the lambda expression inside .Sum(). Changing Decimal sum to decimal? sum doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: The `Decimal?` version of `Sum` just skips over null values. You should be OK now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly (to me) i introduced a possible exception cause trying to make my code more robust!
The right way to write robust code is the following:

```
Decimal sum = MyDataContext.MyTable.Where(el => el.Client == selectedClien).Sum(el => el.Value).GetValueOrDefault(0);
```

As stated in a comment above and in the msdn documentation the

```
Enumerable.Sum<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Nullable<Decimal>>)
```

is robust against null values and empty collections. GetValueOrDefault() assures it returns a non null Decimal.

Anyway it is still not very clear why the initial code throws exception.

Answer (score -1):

I've written an extension to avoid that.

```
    public static decimal? SafeSum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, decimal?> selector)
    {
        try
        {
            return source.Sum(selector);
        }
        catch
        {
            /* ignore exception */
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a way to hide the try/catch block I would like to avoid.

Comment: (a) This won't compile. (b) If `Sum` throws an exception, it's _not_ because `source` is an empty enumerable. This will just mask whatever the real issue is.

Comment: @Rawling I've fixed the compile errors, thanks. The code provided blow is just a sample, which is to avoid the exception. I think we could surely log the exception if we need robust codes.

Comment: Not good to knowingly throw and ignore exceptions like this. Very slow and intensive for a mere sum!